# How to union 2 select without duplication

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

**Iterated question**

Is this possible to get this Output using codeigniter in a single query  using Codeigniter Mysql?

```
oid |  count(waiters) as total_waiters
----+-------------------------------
1   |      1 <-- john will be count as 1 even if assigned to 2 room
2   |      1
3   |      2 <-- count is 2 because different waiters are assigned with different room
4   |      0
```

---

Order table

```
oid |  name 
----+-------
1   |   aa   
2   |   bb   
3   |   cc   
4   |   dd
```

Room table

```
Rid |  oid  |  waiter_assigned
----+-------+-----------------
1   |   1   |     john
2   |   1   |     john
3   |   2   |     john
4   |   3   |     mike
5   |   3   |     dude
```

---

I tried using union

```
$this->db->select('o.oid, "" AS tot_book_thera');
$this->db->from('order o');
$query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select('r.oid, count(r.waiter_assigned) AS total_waiters');
$this->db->from('room r');
$this->db->group_by('r.waiter_assigned');
$query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
```

But I get this...

```
oid |  count(waiters) as total_waiters
----+-------------------------------
1   |      1 
2   |      1
3   |      2
1   |      '' <-- not sure how to combine it with the 1st or how to exclude this or remove this...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks guys!

Comment: You should be reading about how `GROUP BY` should be [handled](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) .. seeing `select('o.*,`  and `group_by('o.oid')`... `select('o.*,` and `group_by('r.waiter_assigned')` tells me you don't have a clue what might be wrong with it and or how to use `GROUP BY` correctly in the SQL language in general ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I understand but I don't know what to use anymore if should I use `GROUP BY` or other codes...

Comment: the only way these queries are valid is when functional dependency could be used.. Anyhow let me see if i understand the logics behide the output..

Comment: @RaymondNijland hmmm alright so if I remove my group by there will there be possible solution? Appreciate your help I'll update my title and other details if needed to remove the confusion

Comment: Needed to do something else first anyhow the main problem here to get that resultset is you need to join, and "unduplicate" with `GROUP BY` on `oid` because you need to use `COUNT(..)` besides that there is not really a clear separation from  `oid` from `Rid` from MySQL 's point of view that why you don't that count separation .. But i need to go now for a few hours and didn't have to time to format a whole query and answer but consider the difference between https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s5B1Zxp5tSrf87JcSQToKW/0 and https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s5B1Zxp5tSrf87JcSQToKW/0

Comment: ..You will need to use a subquery on that second one to filter that resultset to get your expected resultset .. hope it gets you closer to your answer

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks, hope someone will could still help me get the solution using a single query but if not guest need to use 2 queries (which might slow down a little bit) the processing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea. But as others have stated, GROUP BY is your best friend here. Also, make use of DISTINCT to get rid of counting a waiter twice for the same order. This is how your code should look like

```
// An inner select query whose purpose is to count all waiter per room
// The key here is to group them by `oid` since we are interested in the order
// Also, in the count(), use DISTINCT to avoid counting duplicates
$this->db->select('room.oid, count(DISTINCT room.waiter_assigned) AS total_waiters');
$this->db->from('room');
$this->db->group_by('room.oid');
$query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

// If you run $this->db->query($query1)->result(); you should see
oid |  total_waiters
----+-------------------------------
1   |      1
2   |      1
3   |      2

// This is how you would use this table query in a join.
// LEFT JOIN also considers those rooms without waiters
// IFNULL() ensures that you get a 0 instead of null for rooms that have no waiters
$this->db->select('order.oid, order.name, IFNULL(joinTable.total_waiters, 0) AS total_waiters');
$this->db->from('order');
$this->db->join('('.$query1.') joinTable', 'joinTable.oid = order.oid', 'left');
$this->db->get()->result();

// you should see
oid |  name     |  total_waiters
----+-----------+-------------------------
1   |  aa       |      1
2   |  bb       |      1
3   |  cc       |      2
4   |  dd       |      0
```

Here is the raw SQL statement

```
SELECT order.oid, order.name, IFNULL(joinTable.total_waiters, 0) AS total_waiters
FROM order
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT room.oid, count(DISTINCT room.waiter_assigned) AS total_waiters  
    FROM room
    GROUP BY room.oid
) joinTable ON joinTable.oid = order.oid
```

Comment: Thank you @yesigye it did work! wondering if does make it faster than make forloop in getting total waiter...

Comment: For a small query like this one, performance doesn't really matter. I recommend you use the DBMS as DBMS are designed to optimize on joins. Using PHP would require you to use loops and if else statements which you will have to maintain and optimize yourself.